# HTTPS:// Port change during DNS Redirection

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, https, nat

I am trying to find a way to redirect HTTPS:// traffic to a custom port during a DNS Redirection.

EG:
What the client types
Client.Domain.com

Where the client is redirected to
Client.Domain.com:8443

i would prefer to be able to redirect without the client seeing the port change.

My current concept would require a hosted DNS Solution with a virtual router, (which i'm not even sure would work).

(Port 443 is off limits at the endpoint, hence trying to work around without having users typing the port)

Comment: Please do study what DNS can do and see why what you wanted cannot be fulfilled. Reverse proxy is the right way to go.

Comment: DNS redirection is a fairytale. Redirection is a feature provided by the HTTP protocol, and it changes the URL. Reverse proxy on port 443 is the solution.